# Is there a way to fetch regions that my project is using in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, region

I'm using GCP CLI. Is there a command to fetch the regions that a specific project is using?

All I could see was all available regions that my project can use but not the one that my project's using.

Comment: I am not aware of a command that will do this for you. You can use Google Asset Inventory and then search for the `location` key. https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources) and use the query

```
gcloud asset search-all-resources | grep zone
```

You can refine your query for [specific resource api](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types) using the `--asset-type` flag